# Attempting to install AWS Elastic Beanstalk getting: ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Ameer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm following the instructions on the ELB github
I first run the following command :

```
git clone https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup.git
```

but I'm encountering the following error when I run the second command

```
.\aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup\scripts\bundled_installer
```

I'm using windows 10 and running the commands through cmd, however powershell gives me the same issue.
The error:

```
C:\Users\Ameer : The term 'C:\Users\Ameer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:\Users\Ameer Rayan\Desktop\Blog_Project\aws-elastic-beanst ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Ameer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Exiting due to failure

Comment: try updating the version of PowerShellll

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-setup/issues/59#issuecomment-551964412 if this helps